# value changed in ng-model in templatedUrl is undefined in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, directive, angular-ngmodel

#### initially when i load it works fine but when i change the value in template URl for ng-model scope.value is undefined inside my link. i am making directive for datepicker bootstrap angularjs.

```
dateTime .directive("DatePicker", function(){
            
             return {
                        restrict: "E",
                        transclude: true,
                        require: "ngModel",
                        scope:{
                            ngModel: "=",
                            dateOptions: "=",
                            opened: "="
                        },
            
                        link: function($scope, element, attrs, datepickerModel) {
            
                            $scope.open = function(event){
                                event.preventDefault();
                                event.stopPropagation();
                                $scope.opened = true;
                            };
            
                            $scope.myModel = new Date();
                            datepickerModel.$setViewValue($scope.myModel);
            
                            $scope.$watch('myModel',function(){
                                console.log("value changed"+$scope.myModel);
                                datepickerModel.$setViewValue($scope.myModel);
                                console.log($scope.myModel);
                            })
            
                        template: ' <input type="date" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="myModel" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />'
                    }
                })
```

Comment: <date-picker  ng-model="myModel" date-options="dateOptions" opened="opened"/> -- this is my directive and want to bind myModel with the template myModel.

Comment: You should use 'template' instead of 'templateUrl'.

Using templateUrl will make angular load your templates from the defined url, which in this case, is wrong.

Comment: yes i changed to template but still have same issue :(

Comment: I didn't use custom directive.. used two controllers and defined the main scope in parent controller and used date picker controller ng-change value in parent controller its works for me  for now but still have question why directive doesnt get the change ng-model from template... to me it seems like model is not updated at all.